Can access Provider using Nested Providers
I have a Flutter app that has a main localization provider, which is located at the root of my app. I then have a provider I want to provide only to the 'registration' route (which itself has a number of subroutes) since it handles all of the business logic and data associated with Registration. However, when I do this I get an error where I can't use Provider.of because it says the provider was not provided by the context. What am I doing wrong? This seems like it should work from everything I have read. I have my code below, but I have omitted the all of the simple logic checks and such that are unrelated
The error occurs in registration_landing.dart on the line:
final registrationService = Provider.of<RegistrationService>(context, listen: false);

main.dart

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  // TBD:
  //  - Check if the user has already logged in to the app previously
  const bool isRegistered = false;
  runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => LocaleProvider(),
      child: const NextGen(isRegistered: isRegistered),
    ),
  );
}

class NextGen extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isRegistered;

  const NextGen({super.key, required this.isRegistered});

  static FirebaseAnalytics analytics = FirebaseAnalytics.instance;
  static FirebaseAnalyticsObserver observer = FirebaseAnalyticsObserver(analytics: analytics);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final localeProvider = Provider.of<LocaleProvider>(context);

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Training',
      key: const Key('homepage'),
      theme: appTheme,
      locale: localeProvider.locale,
      localizationsDelegates: const [
        AppLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: localeProvider.locales,
      navigatorObservers: <NavigatorObserver>[observer],
      home: isRegistered ? const Dashboard() : const RegistrationLanding(),
      routes: {
        'registration': (context) => ChangeNotifierProvider(
              create: (_) => RegistrationService(
                registrationApi: RegistrationApi(),
              ),
              child: const RegistrationNavigator(),
            ),
        'dashboard': (context) => const Dashboard(),
        'settings': (context) => const Settings(),
      },
    );
  }
}

registration_navigator.dart:
class RegistrationNavigator extends StatelessWidget {
  const RegistrationNavigator({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Navigator(
      initialRoute: '/',
      onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
        WidgetBuilder builder;
        switch (settings.name) {
          case '/':
            builder = (BuildContext context) => const RegistrationLanding();
            break;
          case '/personal_info':
            builder = (BuildContext context) => const PersonalInfoPage();
            break;
          case '/success':
            builder = (BuildContext context) => const RegistrationSuccess();
            break;
          default:
            throw Exception('Invalid route: ${settings.name}');
        }
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: builder, settings: settings);
      },
    );
  }
}

registration_landing.dart
class RegistrationLanding extends StatefulWidget {
  const RegistrationLanding({super.key});

  @override
  RegistrationLandingState createState() => RegistrationLandingState();
}

class RegistrationLandingState extends State<RegistrationLanding> {
  Future<void> submitInformation(BuildContext context) async {
    final registrationService = Provider.of<RegistrationService>(context, listen: false);
    await registrationService.submitEmailAndDob(
      context,
      _emailController.text,
      _dobController.text,
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Setting up stuff
  }

  // Skipping over a number of methods

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Builder(
      builder: (context) {
        return Scaffold(
          key: const Key('registration-landing-page'),
          body: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      const SizedBox(height: 80),
                      const Center(
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            SizedBox(height: 40),
                            TitleLarge('Welcome'),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 20),
                      SingleLineTextEdit(
                        key: const Key('email'),
                        label: 'Email',
                        controller: _emailController,
                        validator: _isEmailInvalid,
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 20),
                      SingleLineTextEdit(
                        key: const Key('date-of-birth'),
                        label: 'Date of Birth',
                        controller: _dobController,
                        readOnly: true,
                        onTap: () => _selectDate(context),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 5),
                      const InfoBlock('We will never sell your personal information.'),
                      const SizedBox(height: 15),
                      BasicDropdown<Country>(
                        label: 'Location',
                        key: const Key('location'),
                        items: _locations,
                        hint: 'Select a Location',
                        itemLabel: (value) => value.displayName,
                        selectedValue: _selectedLocation,
                        onChanged: (newValue) {
                          setState(() {
                            _selectedLocation = newValue;
                            _updateLocationValidation(newValue);
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 50),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              StickyRoundedButton(
                'Continue',
                () {
                  GetIt.instance<HttpClient>().updateApiLocation(_selectedLocation!);
                  submitInformation(context);
                },
                width: 203,
                height: 54,
                enabled: _isFormValid,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

Thanks a ton for any help!

I recommend having a look at https://riverpod.dev/docs/introduction/why_riverpod the replacement of provider. Using riverpod, providers are not connected to a context and are in my opinion easier to use.
